# Display text/shape at a specified time in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I've got problem with javaFX.
I want to display time in App Window every 1000ms.

```
public class Main extends Application {

StackPane root = new StackPane();
Time time;
Text t1;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00FF00");
    primaryStage.setTitle("My App");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 800));
    primaryStage.show();
    checkTime();


    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void checkTime(){
    time = new Time();
    time.start();
}

public void displayTime(int hour, int minute, int second){
    t1= new Text(200, 50, hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
    root.getChildren().add(t1);
}


}
```

And that's second class:

```
package sample;


import java.util.Calendar;

public class Time extends Thread {

Thread t;
public int hour;
public int minute;
public int second;
Calendar calendar;
Main main = new Main();


Time() {
}

public void run() {
    for (; ; ) {
        try {
            getTime();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}

public void start() {
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();

}

public void getTime() {
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    System.out.println(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
    main.displayTime(hour, minute, second);

}


}
```

I would like it to work in a similar way to a digital clock. In the next phases of the project I will want to use this way similarly to other 2D figures.

At this point, after switching on the application, the time spent in the console is correct. However, I would like exactly the same time to be displayed in the application window, at this moment only the background is displayed and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Most of the time you wouldn't need to extend directly from `Thread`, because JavaFX has things like `Timeline` that can act as timers. Having that `Time` class is perfectly fine if you think it is necessary (due to other reasons which you did not specify).
2. Extending from `Thread` and creating another `Thread` is definitely unnecessary though. When `Time` class extends `Thread`, it itself is already a `Thread`.
3. You are creating a new instance of `Main` in `Time`. `Main` is supposed to create `Time` and pass in itself to `Time`, otherwise `Time` would not hold the reference of the original `Main` object.
4. I think you will definitely get some exception at runtime even when you solve #3. You are directly modifying the scene graph via non-JavaFX Application Thread (i.e. your Time class thread). Furthermore, you are creating a new `Text` object each `Time` cycle, so even if there are no exceptions, these `Text` objects are going to overlap one another.

If you wants to retain the `Time` class for other special reasons, then this is generally what you should be doing:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Time time;
    Text t1 = new Text(); // Instantiates only once

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #00FF00");
        primaryStage.setTitle("My App");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 800));
        primaryStage.show();

        root.getChildren().add(t1);

        checkTime();


        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void checkTime(){
        time = new Time(this); // Pass ownself into Time
        time.start();
    }

    public void updateTime(int hour, int minute, int second){
        Platform.runLater(() -> t1.setText(200, 50, hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second));
    }
}
```

```
public class Time extends Thread {
    //Thread t; // Not needed
    public int hour;
    public int minute;
    public int second;
    Calendar calendar;
    Main main; // Don't instantiate

    // Pass in the main object
    Time(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (; ; ) {
            try {
                getTime();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    // This is not needed, Time class has its own start() method, which will call its run() method.
    //public void start() {
    //    t = new Thread(this);
    //    t.start();
    //}

    public void getTime() {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        System.out.println(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
        main.updateTime(hour, minute, second); // Update main
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the better way of closing the app (i.e. one that would also work when calling `Stage.close` from code) would be to use a daemon thread: Add `setDaemon(true);` to the `Time` constructor and remove the `onCloseRequest` handler. Furthermore the `Time` class should be rewritten a bit according to the information hiding principle: all the fields should be `private` (or converted to local variables) and the `getTime` method should probably not be `public` either. Also the `main` field could be made `final`. `Main.checkTime` shouldn't be publick either...

Comment: @fabian Yup, there are quite a number of issues (some are minor) with the codes OP gave, I mainly pointed out those that will actually affect whether the whole thing would work or not... well, except for #2 which I felt irritated enough that I needed to voice it out ;D